# Windows 10 and Samsung TV monitor both think 4K resolution is displayed but it is not, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, 4k-resolution

I have Windows 10 Pro on a desktop machine and a Samsung 4K TV which I use a monitor. Previously the desktop worked fine with a different Samsung 4K TV. 4K resolution was displayed without any problems.  Also, the Samsung I am having trouble with previously worked with another desktop (Ubuntu), and again, 4K was fine.

But I now I moved this Samsung to this desktop, and something strange happens.  Both Windows and the monitor think the resolution displayed is 4K. Control Panel System Settings Display reports current resolution is 3840x2160, 60Hz.  Also, the monitor, when it starts up, reports the same thing.

But it is not 4K! I can see it and measure it by hand with a Pixel Ruler app, 1280x720. Also, I see the whole desktop on the screen, and nothing is hiding to which I can scroll. In other words, Windows 10 windows manager system app knows that it is 1280x720. Display scaling is set to 100%, and image fills the screen.

I have the latest drivers for the video card, and I downloaded and installed the latest firmware for the monitor.  The Device Manager under Monitor reports Generic PnP Monitor, but that is the same as it reported with the previous Samsung Monitor and 4K was fine. I do have the latest Windows PnP Monitor driver. Samsung doesn't provide a driver for the TV, only the firmware.

Comment: does the image fill the physical screen? what are your display scaling settings set to?

Comment: Does Samsung provide a driver for the TV?

Comment: @FrankThomas yes images fill the screen and no more, display scaling is 100%, default

Comment: @Peregrino69 Samsung provides firmware which is installed on the TV itself, not a driver for the OS, firmware is up to date

Comment: @MarkGaleck It's better to update the question than answer in comments. This way all relevant info is available for everyone without reading through commentaries. I already added info about scaling and driver, it will be visible once a senior member of the community accepts the edit.

Comment: @Peregrino69 thank you... I wish someone knew what to do :) I know, a complete format and then reinstall of Windows 10 will fix it, of course.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Sincerely wish I could help further, but as I don't run Windows or own a TV... before going to that direction I'd ensure my Win is up-to-date, then check what happens if I delete all display- and videocard -devices in display manager and reboot. Windows should find them again and install new drivers. That just might do the trick.